# UITableView Scroll animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make a tableview witch scrolls automatically in very slow speed to the bottom and then goes back to the top and starts again in a loop. The user also have to be able to scroll independently , I tried with 
`tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(...))` with no luck, also tried with  `tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(...)`again with no luck.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried. In particular for the scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Comment: `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: 0)
            tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: animated)` it is scrolling but the speed is very fast and I think there is no way to make it slower

Comment: You should update your question with your code. you will need to set up an NSTimer and call this code with an increasing destination row number, resetting it to 0 when you scroll the last row. You are also going to have decide what you are going to do when the user scrolls manually - e.g. Pause the automatic scrolling for some period.

Comment: `var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`      `func update() {
        index++
        self.firstTableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: index, y: index, width: 400, height: 129), animated: true)
        
    }` again with no luck . When user scrolls manually I  want that animation to continue from where the user lefts of

Comment: Again, please edit your question to include your code rather than adding it to a comment, but scroll react to visible with an increasing value of index won't work - you need index to increment by the row height. Better to use scrollToRowAtIndexPath.